# How to get ServiceStack to format Guids with dashes when using JSON?

Tags: c#, json, servicestack, guid

Using ServiceStack to return a simple User object from a Post.

The user object  is pretty simple:

```
public class User
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
}
```

The post method:

```
public override object OnPost(User user)
{
    User newUser;
    // Do stuff to user...
    return newUser;
}
```

My issue is that ServiceStack formats the Guid without dashes, so the JSON response looks e.g. like this:

```
{"id":"c884ce020ec94c65a8788c2ddc500434","username":"new user name"}
```

The client is an Android/Java client and the UUID.fromString() method does get upset about this format.

Is there any way to force ServiceStack to return a Guid formatted with dashes?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

you can override your Guid serializer as

```
ServiceStack.Text.JsConfig<Guid>.SerializeFn = guid => guid.ToString();
```

Comment: FYI, you need to override Guid? as well if you want the same serialization to happen for nullable Guids.

Comment: using ToString("D") more better, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/97af8hh4.aspx

Comment: @LiuPeng: There is no `ToString(string format)` for `Guid?` (any  `Nullable<T>`)